# URLClassLoader not working

Tags: java, urlclassloader

I want to load a file in the directory *F:/badge-dao/bin/com/badge/dao/impl/*, named *BadgeDaoImpl*. I am writing and testing the following code.

If I change the directory or the class name, it throws an exception. For the following code, which I suppose should work, it do not throw a classNotFoundException, but rather halts and take the control to EventTable's finally block.

Can you please tell me where I am getting it wrong.

```
URL[] urls = {new URL("file:/F:/badge-dao/bin/com/badge/dao/impl/")};

ClassLoader parentClassLoader = project.getClass().getClassLoader();

URLClassLoader classLoader = new URLClassLoader(urls, parentClassLoader);

selectedClass = classLoader.loadClass("BadgeDaoImpl");
```

Comment: Are you sure that `bin` is *not* your real classpath directory and you really want to load `com.badge.dao.impl.BadgeDaoImpl`? Also, what `finally` block are you talking about?

Comment: Yes, I am working on a eclipse plugin, and it is not the bin of the plugin rather, the bin folder of the project selected in the workspace. So, I suppose it is not the classpath included in the default classloader, but I do not have lot of experience with ClassLoading.

Answer (score 4):

Package name is a part of full class name, not classpath item, so you need the following:

```
URL[] urls = {new URL("file:/F:/badge-dao/bin")}; 
...
selectedClass = classLoader.loadClass("com.badge.dao.impl.BadgeDaoImpl");
```

In your original code classloader can find a file named `BadgeDaoImpl.class` in `file:/F:/badge-dao/bin/com/badge/dao/impl/`, but its full class name (`com.badge.dao.impl.BadgeDaoImpl`) doesn't match the requested one (`BadgeDaoImpl`), therefore classloader throws a `NoClassDefFoundError`. Since you are catching only `ClassNotFoundException`, it looks like control silently passes to the `finally` block. When you change folder or class names so that `.class` file can't be found, `ClassNotFoundException` is thrown as expected.